# How to install node 18 on Clear Linux OS

Tags: node.js, clearlinux

The native bundle from swupd of clear linux os is [nodejs-basic](https://clearlinux.org/software/bundle/nodejs-basic), but is only on version 16.15 for the moment.
I didn't find any documentation mentioning that they would or would not provide a version 18 (I can't find any doc about node 16 neither to be honest).

Do you have recommendations on how to install node 18?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I actually had to upgrade to the latest clear linux version, which embeds Node 18...